# Inviting Azure application into a tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm able to invite a user into a tenant. After the user confirms the invitation and is assigned a role in a subscription, he/she can view this subscription together with subscriptions from other tenants.

I can list user's subscription from all different tenants using `az account list`

Is it possible to do the same for an Azure application? Somehow invite it and grant it access to a subscription in different tenant? Or, in general, how an application can access resources in different tenant (without using Lighthouse)?

Comment: have you tried assigning a service principal to the application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The security principal for an app is the ServicePrincipal object (much like the security principal for a user is the User object). If an app is configured to be a multi-tenant application, a service principal for that app can be created in any other tenant. Once that service principal has been created, it can be granted a role assignment.

Example using Azure CLI:

1. Log in to tenant A.

   ```
   $ az login --tenant "{tenant-A-id-or-domain}"
   ```
2. In tenant A, configure the app registration (the Application object) to be multi-tenant. (Here we're creating a new one, but you can also update an existing one with `az ad app update`.)

   ```
   $ az ad app create --display-name "App in Tenant A" \
                      --available-to-other-tenants true \
                      --query "appId"

   "74dde9de-56e2-4750-a7cc-5da5f021b897"
   ```
3. Log in to tenant B.

   ```
   $ az login --tenant "{tenant-B-id-or-domain}"
   ```
4. Create a service principal for the app (which was registered in tenant A) in tenant B. Note the value used for `id` is the `appId` of the app registration created in step 2.

   ```
   $ az ad sp create --id "74dde9de-56e2-4750-a7cc-5da5f021b897" \
                     --query "{appId:appId,displayName:displayName}"

   {
     "appId": "4c3e3be1-b735-41b1-a842-f095b9a45849",
     "displayName": "App in Tenant A"
   }
   ```
5. At this point, you can grant the service principal access to something. For example, you can give it a role assignment to a resource in your Azure subscriptions.
6. You can now use the credentials configured on the app registration (i.e. the certificate or client secret), when authenticating into Tenant B, as the app.

Manually creating the service principal object as we've done here is just one approach. Another approach, particularly useful when the app has some sort of user-facing interface (e.g. a web app), is for a user in tenant B to sign in to the app and consent to it. After at least one user has consented to the app, the app's service principal object will be present in Tenant B and it can be granted a role assignment.

Comment: Is this visible in Azure Portal? It seems to work, but I can't see the app in the 2nd tenant in AAD -> App registrations

Comment: In general, "App registrations" lists the definitions of an app or a service. There will only be one, in the tenant where the app is registered (Tenant A, in my example). To see the _instance_ of an app in a tenant (i.e. the service principal), you go to Azure AD > Enterprise apps. (Make sure you set the filter is set to "All applications" if you don't see it.)

Comment: You were right - I didn't see it because I didn't set the filter to "All applications". It's there :)

Comment: `--available-to-other-tenants true` is not valid anymore it seems? (I'm using az cli version 2.40)

<br>

The new setting is `--sign-in-audience AzureADMultipleOrgs`

Comment: In case you want to change a Single-Tenant app to a Multi-Tenant app, use this AZ CLI command : `az ad app update --id {the app id} --set signInAudience=AzureADMultipleOrgs`